# Create regions with DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, region

If I have a X file of type `dx:ThemedWindow` that contains an `AccordionControl`. What region control should I use to create the refrence for that region? I tried `DockPanel` but without success.
The X file look like below.

```
<dxa:AccordionControl>
   <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Home">
      <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Products"/>
      <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Downloads"/>
   </dxa:AccordionItem>
   <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Get Help">
      <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Support"/>
      <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Documentation"/>
   </dxa:AccordionItem>
   <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Client Center"/>
</dxa:AccordionControl>
```

In the `Shell.xaml` I try to get that region by using a `RegionManager`.

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MenuRegion}" />
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous to me, I do not know if you want to have a reion in your window to host the `AccordionControl` or if you want the `AccordionControl` to be a region itself.

### Hosting accordion control in your window

Prism does not have a region adapter for `DockPanel` built-in, but you can declare a `DockPanel` in your window and use a `ContentControl` within it to host the region for the menu.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
   <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MenuRegion}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Then you can [navigate](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Navigation.html) to it with the `RequestNavigate` method of the region manager or you register the view for view discovery with `RegisterViewWithRegion` in your application.

### Accordion control as a region

DevExpress provides a number of region adpaters for Prism out-of-the-box, but none for the `AccordionControl`, see the [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/117848/common-concepts/prism-adapters) for reference.

You have to create a suitable region adapter for **that specific control** yourself. Region adapters can be quite complex, to get started, have a look at these resources.

- [Create a custom Prism region adapter](https://brianlagunas.com/create-a-custom-prism-regionadapter/)
- [XamDockManager–A Prism RegionAdapter](https://brianlagunas.com/xamdockmanagera-prism-regionadapter/)
- [Prism for WPF: Custom Region Adapters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DvtGorOfD8)

Comment: With an appropriate region adapter, what prevents a panel (or `DockPanel`) from hosting a region?

Comment: @Haukinger Nothing. I think that was a misunderstanding, so I removed the ambiguous sentence. I meant that the child control of a region host will not magically become a region.

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress provides you with a set of region adapters for its controls (look at the installation directory at something like components\source\prismadapters).

If there's no region adapter available off the shelf for `AccordionControl`, you'll have to write your own.